# Form validation error message in angular 2

Tags: angular, validation, angular5, angular7

Custom input box validation error message not working in angular2 and required also not working.How to resolve this issue.Anyone know please help me.

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-template-driven-form-validation-kkqcwh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
<app-textbox type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" 
[(inputModel)]="model.firstName" #firstName="ngModel"
 required></app-textbox>
<div *ngIf="f.submitted && firstName.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
<div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with the class `invalid-feedback` which is hiding the element on load.

Try removing this and it works fine.

A suggestion to combine the nested `div` elements which show the error into one and add class conditionally as

```
[class.invalid-feedback]="your condition"
```

Comment: Can you answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55316578/form-custom-fields-validation-angular-2